# same NN architecture-loss is not converging in pytorch but converging in Keras. Results on testdata are also different

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I've developed an architecture using the same number of layers, neurons in each layer, loss function, % of dropout, weight initialization and the same order of operations for both PyTorch architecture and the same random seed. Although I used exactly the same architecture, the loss is going down in Keras and results on the test dataset are superior, whereas in PyTorch the loss is hovering around a particular value not going down and results on the test dataset are nowhere near to Keras results. I used the same preprocessed dataset I am unable to understand where I am making the mistake.
Here is my code.

```
df=https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shrutimechlearn/churn-modelling
#preprocessing
df.columns=df.columns.str.lower()
df['numofproducts'] = df.numofproducts.apply(lambda x: '2+' if x==3 or x==4 else x)
df['numofproducts']=df['numofproducts'].replace({1:'one',2:'two','2+':'twoPlus'})
df['numofproducts']=df['numofproducts'].astype('object')

df.drop(['rownumber','customerid','surname'],axis=1,inplace=True)

catCols=df.select_dtypes('object').columns.to_list()
numCols=df.select_dtypes('number').columns.to_list()
numCols.remove('exited')
print(f'categoryColumns:{catCols} \n numericColumns:{numCols} \n')

## train test split, scaling and up-sampling
dfD=pd.get_dummies(df[catCols],drop_first=True,dtype=int)

#drop catCols from main dataset
target=df.pop('exited')
df.drop(catCols,axis=1,inplace=True)
df1=pd.concat([df,dfD],axis=1)

#train test split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df1,target,test_size=0.2,
                                               random_state=100,stratify=target)
display(x_train.shape,y_train.shape,x_test.shape,y_test.shape)
x_train.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
x_test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
y_train.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
y_test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
sc=StandardScaler()
x_trainS=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_testS=sc.transform(x_test)
display(type(x_trainS),type(x_testS))
smote=SMOTE()
x_trainUS,y_trainUS=smote.fit_resample(x_trainS,y_train)

trainUS=torch.from_numpy(x_trainUS.astype('float32'))
trainLabelsUS=torch.FloatTensor(np.array(y_trainUS))
test=torch.from_numpy(np.array(x_testS).astype('float32'))
testLabels=torch.FloatTensor(np.array(y_test))

##### py torch implementation
class neural_network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hiddenLayer1,hiddenLayer2,output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.fullConnLayer1=nn.Linear(input_size,hiddenLayer1)
        self.fullConnLayer2=nn.Linear(hiddenLayer1,hiddenLayer2)
        self.outputLayer=nn.Linear(hiddenLayer2,output_size)
        self.drpLayer1=nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.drpLayer2=nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.batchNorm1=nn.BatchNorm1d(hiddenLayer1)
        self.batchNorm2=nn.BatchNorm1d(hiddenLayer2)
        
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fullConnLayer1.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fullConnLayer2.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.outputLayer.weight)
    
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # layer 1
        x=self.fullConnLayer1(x)
        x=self.batchNorm1(x)
        x=self.drpLayer1(x)
        x=torch.relu(x)
        
        #layers 2
        x=self.fullConnLayer2(x)
        x=self.batchNorm2(x)
        x=self.drpLayer2(x)
        x=torch.relu(x)
        
        #output layer
        x=torch.sigmoid(self.outputLayer(x))
        return(x)
        

torch.manual_seed(100)
batch_size=512
numIterations=np.ceil(len(trainLabelsUS) / batch_size)
trainSetUS=TensorDataset(trainUS,trainLabelsUS)
trainLoader=DataLoader(trainSetUS,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
testSetS=TensorDataset(test,testLabels)
testLoader=DataLoader(testSetS,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

model=neural_network(12,20,20,1)
lossFunction=nn.BCELoss()
optim=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)
epochs=500
loss=0
epochLoss=[]
batchLoss=[]
for epoch in range(epochs):
    if epoch==0:
        epochLoss.append(np.nan)
    else:
        epochLoss.append(loss.item())
    for i,(data,labels) in enumerate(trainLoader):
        i=i+1
        y_pred=model.forward(data)
        loss=lossFunction(y_pred.flatten(),labels)
        batchLoss.append(loss.item())
        optim.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        if i% 10 ==0:
            print(f'epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs},step {i}/{numIterations},loss: {loss.item()}') 

####### keras model
seed(100)
tf.random.set_seed(100)
modelBD = Sequential()
modelBD.add(Dense(units=20, input_dim=12))
modelBD.add(BatchNormalization())
modelBD.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
modelBD.add(Activation('relu'))
modelBD.add(Dense(units=20))
modelBD.add(BatchNormalization())
modelBD.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
modelBD.add(Activation('relu'))
modelBD.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
modelBD.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
historyBD=modelBD.fit(x_trainUS,y_trainUS,batch_size=512,
                  epochs=500,verbose=True,validation_split=0.2)

#####  pytorch model on test dataset
accuracy: 0.682
precision: 0.37263626251390436
recall: 0.8230958230958231

###### keras model on test dataset
accuracy: 0.83
precision: 0.5788235294117647
recall: 0.6044226044226044
```

[PyTorch Model Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf4Wy.png)
[KerasModelLoss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPCyd.png)

Here is

Answer (score 0):

there might be a lot reason behind it. first of all in your PyTorch implementation, you are applying batch normalization after each linear layer. However, in your Keras implementation, you are applying batch normalization before the activation function.
In your PyTorch implementation, you are using a dropout rate of 0.2 for both dropout layers. However, in your Keras implementation, you are using a dropout rate of 0.2 for the first dropout layer and 0.5 for the second dropout layer. even the weight initialization might not be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In both architectures I am applying linear layer (also called dense in keras), batch norm, dropout followed by relu. My drop out ratio is 0.2 across two layers and across two architectures. Even the weight initialization in both architectures is xavier_glorot (in keras this is by default, in pytorch i used this initialized) This is what amuses me of why does it have to produce two different results?